# Добавлении в SQL запрос условия из обьявленного ранее выражения c параметром в переменной

Tags: sql, sql-server

Задача в добавлении в SQL запрос условия из обьявленного ранее **выражения c параметром** в переменной.
Cмог решить эту задачу пока только через динамический sql (sp_executesql)

**ВАРИАНТ1 - РАБОЧИЙ (через sp_executesql)**

```
--объявляем переменные
DECLARE @wherecondition nvarchar(Max)
DECLARE @sqlcode nvarchar(Max)
--условие, которое нужно будет добавить в код
SET @wherecondition = 'and (Param2 IN (1,2))'
--создаем запрос

set @sqlcode = 'select * from sdol where (Kod < 10) ' + @wherecondition + ' order by Kod' 
--выполняем запрос
exec sp_executesql @sqlcode
```

Но в таком случае неудобно редактировать обьемный код-запрос в MS SQL Managment Studio, он просто не будет подсвечиваться

**ВАРИАНТ2 - КАК ХОЧЕТСЯ СДЕЛАТЬ**

Как можно добавить условие-выражение в sql-запрос без использования sp_executesql, чтобы получилось вроде такого:

```
--объявляем переменные:

DECLARE @wherecondition nvarchar(Max)
--условие, которое нужно будет добавить в код
SET @wherecondition = 'and (Param2 IN (1,2))'
--выполняем запрос с добавленным @wherecondition
select * from sdol where (Kod < 10) + @wherecondition + order by Kod
```

Естественно, так не будет работать, вопрос в том, как сделать добавление выражения из переменной без динамического sql (через sp_executesql) и **передавать в этом выражении именно параметр**, а не только значения.

Comment: Какая у вас версия SQL Server?

Comment: SQL Server 2012. Но до 2017 обновиться не проблема, если есть решение на нём.

Comment: SQL Server 2017 хорош. Допустимо ли передавать параметр в виде списка, разделенного запятыми: '1,2,15' без Param2 IN ?

Comment: Вот загвоздка как раз в том, как сам параметр передавать. Так бы само собой можно было сделать например: where (Kod < 10) and Param2 IN (select @value). "Param2 IN (1,2)" здесь в качестве примера. В самом коде это выглядит как длинное выражение из нескольких параметров.

Comment: В таком случае только динамический SQL

Comment: Все бы хорошо, но большие запросы в динамическом SQL не удобно править в MSSMS.

Comment: Кроме того, такой подход имеет серьезную угрозу безопасности, как SQL-инъекция.